# Beamer: control scope of \pause

Tags: beamer

Is there a way to control the scope of a beamer `\pause`? What I'd like is the following:

```
\begin{frame}
\pausescope{
text1
\pause
text2
}
text3
\end{frame}
```

to generate two slides: text1text3 and text1text2text3. Is there a way to do this?

My use case is with columns---I want information on the right column to appear on all slides and use `\pause` in the left column. As is, the right column only appears after all of the left column's pauses are done.

Comment: I would use the \only{} or \uncover{} commands instead.

Answer (score 1):

`\pause` is a very crude command. For more fine control you can use proper beamer overlays, like `\only`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
text1

\only<2->{text2}

text3
\end{frame}

    
\end{document}
```